# R - format string with brackets and add colon into it

Tags: r

I'm very new to R. I've tried to come up with a code in R which can help me to convert a string with brackets like the string below:

```
( 65   97) ( 80   12) ( 82  832) (108   23)
```

into a format like this:

```
65:97 80:12 82:832 108:23
```

I think I should find the position of the space between each bracket and replace it with : and delete the brackets afterward, but I don't how. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gsub` with back reference as follows:

```
gsub("\\( *(\\d+) +(\\d+) *\\)", "\\1:\\2", "( 65 97) ( 80 12) ( 82 832) (108 23)")

# [1] "65:97 80:12 82:832 108:23"
```

- `\\( *(\\d+) +(\\d+) *\\)` matches a parentheses unit where there are two digits enclosed separated by one or more spaces. `*` here is to match optional spaces between parenthesis and digits.
- at the replacement part, you can use back reference `\\1` and `\\2` to refer the first and second capture groups, i.e. two `(\\d+)` and format them with a colon inserted.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You just made my day.  Just want to understand it completely, the * separates those two capture groups "\\( ?(\\d+) and (\\d+) ?\\ right?

Comment: I should have used ` +` as it is guaranteed that there is a space between two numbers. Yes it separates two capture groups `(\\d+)`, and `\\( *` and ` *\\)` are exact matches of parenthesis and optional spaces.